# Minimum tip to be paid for bill amount B with two kind of coins (x,y) only

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, dynamic-programming, discrete-mathematics

I have two kind of coins (unlimited coins of each type).
The values of these two coins are **x and y**.
I have to pay a bill of amount **B**.

> What minimum amount i will need to pay as **tip**.

```
tip can be any value >=0
```

The objective is to minimize the tip.

I just was thinking about the Dynamic programming approach.Or any Faster method.
Please help.

```
function minTip(x,y,B){
    if(z<=0) return -z;
    return minimum( minTip(x,y,B-x),minTip(x,y,B-y) );
}
```

> Can any one help with the DP approach.??

Comment: Do you know the limits of the input size `B`?

Comment: i say "be a generous tipper" :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need DP to solve this.

First, note that you may as well assume the coins are coprime. Because if they're not then you can only generate multiples of the gcd. Then let g = gcd(x, y) and solve the problem of minimizing the tip T of ceil(B / g) using coins x/g and y/g. Then the solution to the original problem is T*g + g * ceil(B / g) - B.

If x and y *are* coprime, then the largest number you *can't* generate exactly is xy - x - y. (See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66963/largest-integer-that-cant-be-represented-as-a-non-negative-linear-combination-o)

So if B > xy - x - y, then you're guaranteed to be able to pay exactly with 0 tip.

Otherwise, you can find the solution using brute force by trying every possible combination of coin x (and then using the smallest number of y to make at least B). Since B < xy, that's approximately y different values. By swapping the coins if necessary, that means we can solve the problem in the worst case in O(min(x, y)) time.

Putting that together into a single program:

```
def gcd(x, y):
    x, y = min(x, y), max(x, y)
    while x != 0:
        x, y = y % x, x
    return y

def tip(x, y, B):
    g = gcd(x, y)
    if g != 1:
        nB = (B + g - 1) // g
        T = tip(x // g, y // g, (B + g - 1) // g)
        return T * g + nB * g - B
    if B > x * y - x - y:
        # We're guaranteed to be able to make B exactly.
        return 0
    # Swap the coins if necessary so that x is the larger one.
    x, y = max(x, y), min(x, y)
    T = B
    # Try 0, 1, 2, ... B//x+1 of the x coin.
    # More than this isn't necessary since (B//x+1)*x
    # is already greater than or equal to B.
    for i in xrange(B // x + 2):
        # j is the smallest number of y coins
        # such that ix + jy >= B.
        j = max(0, (B - i * x + y - 1) // y)
        T = min(T, i * x + j * y - B)
    return T

print tip(7, 12, 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the solution by doing modulus operation with the maximum value and the modulus operation with small value on remainder from the first operation. You can loop over till you identify the maximum deviation.
A working code can be found at the following bin.

http://jsbin.com/fivikoh/edit?js,console

```
tipReduce(x,y,z) {
     //find minimum and maximum from x and y
     //find the quotient by dividing z with maxValue
     for(//decrease the quotient till 0) {
      //multiply the quotient with max and the divide the reminder
      //with min value, if the reminder is the zero 'return' it, it is the
      //answer. else store the reminder to find the maximum value of the
      //reminder later. That is used for the tip

        var result =  k * maxValue;
       var reminder =  z - result;
       var reminderDivision = reminder % minValue;
       var divisionWithMinValue = Math.floor(reminder/minValue);
       var calcDifference = z - (result + (divisionWithMinValue *     minValue));
    if(calcDifference > smallestPossible) {
     smallestPossible = calcDifference;
     rememberValues = [k, divisionWithMinValue];

    }
    if(reminderDivision === 0) {
      return [{denom: maxValue, count:k},
            {denom:minValue, count: (reminder/minValue)},
            {tip:0}
           ];
      }
  }
```

output function is at the last but one line. Use this to test with different values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please add part of the code inline so that it is available even if the posted link is taken down in the future.

Comment: @Sampada Yeah I updated the code. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

A [*Mixed-Integer Programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) approach will be probably **much faster** (compared to DP).

Here is an example implementation (built with python and [cvxpy](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/index.html)):

```
from cvxpy import *

x_y_vals = [3,7]

def solve(vals, amount):
    vars = Int(2)
    constraints = [sum_entries(mul_elemwise(vals, vars)) >= amount,
                   vars >= 0]
    objective = Minimize(sum_entries(mul_elemwise(vals, vars)))

    prob = Problem(objective, constraints)
    prob.solve(solver=CBC)
    print("status:", prob.status)
    print("optimal diff", prob.value)
    print("optimal var", vars.value)

solve(x_y_vals, 300)
```

Call:

```
solve(x_y_vals, 300)
```

Output:

```
('status:', 'optimal')
('optimal diff', 300.0)
('optimal var', matrix([[  2.],
        [ 42.]]))
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out by **Paul Hankin** (thanks!), there was a modelling error. I fixed it.

**Remark:** The default MIP-solver in CVXPY is only working on *toy-problems*, so we need a better solver (or we run into numerical troubles). Here we use [cbc](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc) which is supported by *cvxpy*, but needs to be installed manually (see the docs).

Comment: This is a neat method, but the minimum tip with coins 3, 7 and a bill of 300 is 0, not 1. I can't see what's wrong with your program though...

Comment: @Paul Hankin This was embarassing. I should have checked the results. I fixed the code (there was modelling problem indeed) and now it looks good. Now we need a better solver though (so we are explicitly choosing cbc).

Answer (score 0):

Take some coin change problem solution with DP ([arbitrary example](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/))

Make array length `B + 1 + min(x, y)`

Fill this array (here you don't need counts, only 0/1 possibility to make a sum)

Look for smallest entry with 1 value in index range [B..B + min(x, y)]